# Count if 'x' occurs in one column AND 'y' occurs in another

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find the percentage of Names that contain the letter "c" and are also male.

I am able to attain each individually, but not together. I am relatively new to coding in python, so I am not sure if an if statement needs to be run, or how to properly run it for this scenario.

```
    len(dogs[dogs['Name'].str.contains('c')])
    len(dogs[dogs['Gender'].str.contains('male')])
```

I would like to know the way to find what contains both 'c' and 'male'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need test substring use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `&` for bitwise AND and for percentage use `mean`, or for count use `sum`:

```
dogs = pd.DataFrame({
         'Name':['abc','c','sa'],
         'Gender':['female','male','female']
})

print (dogs)
  Name  Gender
0  abc  female
1    c    male
2   sa  female

m1 = dogs['Name'].str.contains('c')
m2 = dogs['Gender'].str.contains('male')
print (m1)
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: Name, dtype: bool

print (m2)
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: Gender, dtype: bool

print ((m1 & m2).mean())
0.6666666666666666

print ((m1 & m2).sum())
2
```

If need to check values use [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) or `==`:

```
m1 = dogs['Name'].eq('c')
m2 = dogs['Gender'].eq('male')
```

---

```
m1 = dogs['Name'] == 'c'
m2 = dogs['Gender'] == 'male'

print (m1)
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: Name, dtype: bool

print (m2)
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: Gender, dtype: bool

print ((m1 & m2).mean())
0.3333333333333333

print ((m1 & m2).sum())
1
```